# How to run this SQL update statement

Tags: java, sql

I've read the documentation but for some reason it just isn't clicking. This is the update I want to run:

```
vSQL = "UPDATE consultant SET Availability = 'Available' FROM consultant JOIN contract ON consultant_id = contract_lead WHERE contract_end < sysdate ";
```

Any chance someone can give me the solution and explanation?

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) *Explain* the logic you want to implement.  (3) Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `sysdate` implies (to me) that you are using Oracle.  You probably want to set the availability to `'Available'` to any consultant where the maximum end date is in the past.  That would be:

```
UPDATE consultant c
    SET Availability = 'Available' 
    WHERE (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(co.contract_end), DATE '2000-01-01')
           FROM contract co
           WHERE c.consultant_id = co.contract_lead
          ) < sysdate;
```

EDIT (in response to the comment):

```
UPDATE consultant c
    SET Availability = 'Available' 
    WHERE (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(COALESCE(co.contract_end, sysdate)), DATE '2000-01-01')
           FROM contract co
           WHERE c.consultant_id = co.contract_lead
          ) < sysdate;
```

Comment: This was brilliant thanks! Is there anyway I can make it so the availability doesn't update if contract_end is null?